# Bluetooth speaker failed back to phone speaker when there's a power status change on a GSI ROM

Tags: custom-roms, battery, bluetooth, speaker, gsi

##### Current Behavior:

When my Bluetooth earphone reports a power change to the phone, the Bluetooth disconnects and falls back to the phone speaker.

##### The problem

The Bluetooth speaker falls back to the phone speaker when there's a power status change.

##### Device information

Device: Redmi Note 11T 5G (codename: evergo)

Build Flavor: PixelExperience_Plus_arm64-ab-13.0-20230104-UNOFFICIAL.img.xz

##### Logs

```
01-07 21:40:12.443  4947  5548 E bluetooth: packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/bta/dm/bta_dm_pm.cc:1016 bta_dm_pm_btm_status: Received unknown power mode status event:5
01-07 21:40:13.605  4947  5548 I bluetooth: packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/gatt/gatt_api.cc:1410 GATT_Disconnect: conn_id=6
01-07 21:40:13.605  4947  5548 I bluetooth: packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/gatt/gatt_main.cc:328 gatt_update_app_hold_link_status: removed gatt_if=6
01-07 21:40:13.605  4947  5548 I bluetooth: packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/eatt/eatt_impl.h:880 disconnect:  Device: [Bluetooth Addreess here, removed], cid: 0xffff
01-07 21:40:13.605  4947  5548 I bluetooth: packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/gatt/gatt_main.cc:392 gatt_update_app_use_link_flag: GATT fixed channel is no longer useful, start link idle timer for 1 seconds
01-07 21:40:13.605  4947  5548 I bluetooth: packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/gatt/gatt_api.cc:1084 GATT_SetIdleTimeout: idle_timeout=1, status=1, (1-OK 0-not performed)
01-07 21:40:13.606  4947  5548 W bluetooth: packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/gatt/gatt_main.cc:324 gatt_update_app_hold_link_status: attempt to remove non-existing gatt_if=6
01-07 21:40:13.606  4947  5548 I bluetooth: packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/gatt/gatt_main.cc:356 gatt_update_app_use_link_flag: App status is not updated for gatt_if=6
01-07 21:40:14.651  4947  5548 E bluetooth: packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/btm/btm_sco.cc:957 btm_sco_on_disconnected: Unable to find sco connection
01-07 21:40:14.652  4947  5548 I bluetooth: packages/modules/Bluetooth/system/stack/gap/gap_ble.cc:303 client_connect_cback: No active GAP service found for peer:xx:xx:xx:xx:f1:47 callback:Disconnected
01-07 21:40:14.681  1737  1764 W BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED flg=0x5000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.apps.wearables.maestro.companion/.connectivity.ClassicBTReceiver requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT due to sender com.android.bluetooth (uid 1002)
```